# Payload reader from PHP to Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code below that process an ASCII character in PHP and transform it in a real message:

```
$message = '';

$len = ord($buffer[1]) & 127;

$masks = null;
$data = null;

if ($len === 126) {
    $masks = substr($buffer, 4, 4);
    $data = substr($buffer, 8);
}
elseif($len === 127) {
    $masks = substr($buffer, 10, 4);
    $data = substr($buffer, 14);
} else {
    $masks = substr($buffer, 2, 4);
    $data = substr($buffer, 6);
}

for ($index = 0; $index < strlen($data); $index++) {
    $message. = $data[$index] ^ $masks[$index % 4];
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in objective-c, for this:

```
NSData * buffer = self.data;

NSString * mystring = [
    [NSString alloc] initWithData: buffer encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unichar len = [mystring characterAtIndex: 1] & 127;

NSString * masks = nil;
NSString * data = nil;

NSString * message = @"";

if (len == 126) {
    masks = [mystring substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(4, 4)];
    data = [mystring substringToIndex: 8];
} else if (len == 127) {
    masks = [mystring substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(10, 4)];
    data = [mystring substringToIndex: 14];
} else {
    masks = [mystring substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
    data = [mystring substringToIndex: 6];
}

for (int index = 0; index < [data length]; index++) {
    [message stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",
    data[index] ^ masks[index % 4]]];
}
```

This code has a little problem, I'm receiving this error message:

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type
>   'NSString*'

Why and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When assigning to `len` you use `characterAtIndex:` to obtain a character from `mystring`.

Later when trying to access characters in `data` and `masks` you instead try to use `[]` indexing, and the compiler advises you:

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSString*'

Use `characterAtIndex:`, as you did when indexing `mystring`.

Note that `characterAtIndex` returns back a `unichar` - the type of `len` - and this is 16-bits not an 8-bit byte. You may be better off using the `NSString` method `cStringUsingEncoding`, or one of its siblings, and processing you data as a C string or array of bytes.

HTH